# Validar datos de un input con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy creando un Form para uso de escaneo.
Lo que quiero hacer es que, al momento de que un usuario escanee, este campo se valide para que le haga saber si escaneo bien o no el campo. Les explico con el codigo. Soy un poco nuevo con esto de JS y validar campos. Y no logro hacer que se valide el campo.

Aquí tengo el codigo del formulario, el cual puede ser desplegado hasta 40 filas para capturar/escanear. Como pueden observar, la validacion la tengo en un input.

```
<form method="post" name="crear-in" id="crear_in" action="modelo-in.php" onsubmit="return validar();">

                    <!-- Los datos se pueden desplegar hasta 40 veces -->
                      <?php
                      for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) { ?>
                        <tr class="fila-fija">

                          <input type="hidden" style="width : 140px;" id="customer<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer[]" placeholder="customer" />
                          <input type="hidden" id="folio<?php echo ($i); ?>" name="folio[]" value="<?php echo $f; ?>">
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="skmx_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="skmx_pn[]" placeholder="SKMX PN" onchange="consult();" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 180px;" id="description<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="description[]" placeholder="Description" readonly /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="customer_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer_pn[]" placeholder="Customer PN" readonly /></td>
                          <td><input onkeypress='return validarSO(event)' class="so" type="text" style="width : 120px;" id="shop_order<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="shop_order[]" placeholder="# Shop Order" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 70px;" id="po<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="po[]" placeholder="# P.O." /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 100px;" id="lote<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="lote[]" placeholder="Lote" /></td>
                          <td><input class="quantity" type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="quantity<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="location<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="location[]" placeholder="Location" value="Pasillo" readonly /></td>
                          <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="incoming<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="incoming[]" placeholder="" readonly /></td>

                        </tr>
                      <?php } ?>

                      <!-- </table> -->
                      <div class="box-footer">
                        <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
                        <button type="submit" id="btn-in-out" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Crear</button>

                      </div>

                    </form>
```

Estuve investigando en internet sobre Regular expressions y arme el siguiente codigo de JS.
Cabe resaltar que el formato que quiero es **WK00-0000**.

**NOTAS**

Estoy usando getElementsByClassName por que estos campos pueden ser desplegados hasta 40 veces, aunque no estoy seguro si es una buena forma de hacerlo.
Además de que la mayoria de las veces este sera escaneado con la configuracion del enter del escaner.

```
function validarSO(event) {
                    var so = document.getElementsByClassName("so").value;
                    var exp = /^ [W]{1}[K]{1} \d{2} - \d {4} $/

                    if (exp.test(so)) {
                      alert("Se valido el SK");
                    } else {
                      alert("No se valido");
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
```

Estoy abierto a sugerencias si en algún lado estoy haciendo algo mal. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te hago las siguientes recomendaciones:

1. Ten cuidado con las expresiones regulares y los espacios que hay en ellas, si quieres un evaluar un formato como **WK00-0000** entonces la expresión debería de ser `/^[W]{1}[K]{1}\d{2}-\d{4}$/` y no la que estás usando que incluye espacios extra.
2. Pasa `this` a la función desde el evento para poder acceder al elemento que necesita validarse, en este caso acceder al atributo `value` del mismo para hacer la validación.
3. Para no interrumpir al usuario mientras escribe en el elemento de tipo `input` te recomiendo que busques otro evento, yo en el ejemplo que te brindo como solución utilizo `onchange`.

Tomando en cuenta esto, tú código quedaría así:

```js
function validarSO(e) {
  var so = e.value;
  console.log(so);
  var exp = /^[W]{1}[K]{1}\d{2}-\d{4}$/

  if (exp.test(so)) {
    alert("Se valido el SK");
  } else {
    alert("No se valido");
    e.value="";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="crear-in" id="crear_in" action="modelo-in.php" onsubmit="return validar();">

  <!-- Los datos se pueden desplegar hasta 40 veces -->
  <?php
                      for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) { ?>
    <tr class="fila-fija">

      <input type="hidden" style="width : 140px;" id="customer<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer[]" placeholder="customer" />
      <input type="hidden" id="folio<?php echo ($i); ?>" name="folio[]" value="<?php echo $f; ?>">
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="skmx_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="skmx_pn[]" placeholder="SKMX PN" onchange="consult();" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 180px;" id="description<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="description[]" placeholder="Description" readonly /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 90px;" id="customer_pn<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="customer_pn[]" placeholder="Customer PN" readonly /></td>
      <td><input onchange='return validarSO(this)' class="so" type="text" style="width : 120px;" id="shop_order<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="shop_order[]" placeholder="# Shop Order" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 70px;" id="po<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="po[]" placeholder="# P.O." /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 100px;" id="lote<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="lote[]" placeholder="Lote" /></td>
      <td><input class="quantity" type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="quantity<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="quantity[]" placeholder="Quantity" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="location<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="location[]" placeholder="Location" value="Pasillo" readonly /></td>
      <td><input type="text" style="width : 60px;" id="incoming<?php echo ($i); ?>" required name="incoming[]" placeholder="" readonly /></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    <!-- </table> -->
    <div class="box-footer">
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
      <button type="submit" id="btn-in-out" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Crear</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

Suerte programando! Espero que esto te sea de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Andaba probandolo y si funciona, el detalle es que si se escanea un valor que no cumple con la validacion, me da la alerta **alert("No se valido");** , sin embargo, aun así me pone los valores en el input. No se si entre aquí pero queria que si no era correcto el valor escaneado, simplemente me mandara la alerta y que no me ingresara nada en el Input.

Comment: Es que el `input` adquiere el valor *antes* de que se haga la validación. A ver si te entiendo... ¿Lo que quieres es que si la validación falla que se borren los datos del input?

Comment: Creo que tienes razon, y si, si no es correcta la validacion, que no se muestre nada en el input o como tu lo dices, que se borre.

Comment: Ya te entiendo, en este caso nada más cambias el `value` del input por medio de JS, te voy a actualizar la respuesta para incluir este comportamiento.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona a la perfeccion, agradezco mucho tu tiempo y ayuda.